# TaskPane loading in to the wrong word 2013 document

Tags: ms-word, office-js

We have a functionality like downloading a doc from there server which will have a task pane but the problem is when i have a word doc opened already ( may be some random doc) and i try to download a doc from server. The task pane gets added to the the existing doc and the downloaded doc has empty task pane.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

P.S : When the doc is downloaded from the server , We add a webextension task pane inclusion on response.  Not sure why it is reflecting in the downloaded document.

Comment: In what way are you adding the add-in?  Code sample would help.

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky We use openxml.office2013 C# webextension class to append the webextension details in the response. `webExtension.AddNamespaceDeclaration("we",
                "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/webextensions/webextension/2010/11");
            var webExtensionStoreReference = new We.WebExtensionStoreReference()
            {
                Id = _settings.Id,
                Version = _settings.Version,
                Store = _settings.Store,
                StoreType = _settings.StoreType
            };`

Comment: If you open the newly-generated document "standalone" with no existing document running, what happens then?  A fuller code snippet may still be helpful (I.e., to see the entire generation flow)

Comment: It works fine in that case . The issue occurs only when there is an word document open already.

Comment: by any chance you have a link i can use to repro this issue?